# MediaWiki: Auto-Create pages from changing directory content

Tags: automation, wiki, mediawiki, bots, mediawiki-api

I try to use MediaWiki as some kind of private collaborative content management system, e.g. people just feed content (image,video,text,other) to a given directory, from which i like MediaWiki to automatically create pages for every single file.

What's the way to go, is there any extension or bot?

Thanks for your concern & best regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find a page creation bot there: http://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/MediaWiki_Bulk_Page_Creator

With some tweaking, you should be able to support various file types.

Comment: can you guide me here. How can i make it work?
where should i put snoopy lib??

Comment: how do i execute script?